# Removing a certain users tweets in searchTwitter

Tags: r, twitter

I was wondering if there is a simple and elegant way of modifying your `searchTwitter()` call so that it removes tweets from a certain user?

I suspect that one solution likely lies with getting that user's tweets form `userTimeline()` and using sets to remove them from your search twitter results, but I was wondering if there be a simpler solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: What would be wrong with putting the logic to subset your result into your `R` code?

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen. I just learned about `twitteR`, but why not `search <- twListToDF(searchTwitter("RStudio"))` and then `search[search$screenName != "StackOverflowR",]`?

Comment: Had totally forgotten about twListtoDF

Works a charm

Many thanks!